# How to split this string by ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to split the string from the last underscore. The string as below:

```
"abc_123_identifier_12345"
```

the output:

```
["abc_123_identifier", "12345"]
```

please tell me if you have same good ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to split it? On the third underscore? Last underscore? Last non-digit character?

Comment: The core team really needs to add `String#rsplit`.

Comment: @Yule on the third underscore

Comment: so abc_123_identifier_671_123 should return "671_123"?

Comment: @Yule " abc_123_identifier_671_123"  should return ["abc_123_identifier_671",  "123"]

Comment: @pangpang, so it's the last one, not the third one then...

Comment: @Yule sorry for my mistake, thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"abc_123_identifier_12345".split(/_(\d+)$/)
#=> ["abc_123_identifier", "12345"]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's nice. I really should make regex my 'go to' solution...

Comment: It may or may not be right answer depending what OP really wants

Comment: this is what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = "abc_123_identifier_12345"
a.rpartition('_') - ['_']
```

output in console

```
[22] pry > a = "abc_123_identifier_12345"
=> "abc_123_identifier_12345"
[23] pry > a.rpartition('_') - ['_']
=> ["abc_123_identifier", "12345"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks more like a pattern matching task than a splitting task for me:

```
[1] pry(main)> /^(.*)_(\d*)$/.match("abc_123_identifier_12345").captures
=> ["abc_123_identifier", "12345"]
```